# MySql InnoDB Deadlock while inserting bulk data in a Tree-like-Table

Tags: mysql, database

Tried with latest MySql 5.6.23

Getting '**Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction**' when i insert around 5000 records to the below table. Please note that this error is only getting *generated in client locations. In our DEV/TEST Environment, records are getting inserted smoothly.*

The below table shows a **Parent-Child Hierarchy(Tree like)**. Also it has got some foreign key constratins and other Index-Keys as well(shown below)

```
CREATE TABLE `ex_result` (
  `Result_ID` varchar(63) NOT NULL,
  `ParentResult_ID` varchar(63) DEFAULT NULL,
  `StepNumber` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Type` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `DB_ID` varchar(63) NOT NULL,
  `Session_ID` varchar(63) NOT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `TotalTime` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `FunctionCall` mediumtext,
  `FunctionResult` mediumtext,
  `ToolTime` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `PluginName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Screenshot_FID` varchar(63) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IsNegative` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ContinueOnError` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WantSnapshot` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Message` mediumtext,
  `ResultCode` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Output` mediumtext,
  `InputArguments` mediumtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Result_ID`),
  KEY `FK_ex_result_session` (`Session_ID`),
  KEY `FK_ex_result_self` (`ParentResult_ID`),
  KEY `FK_ex_result_Screenshot` (`Screenshot_FID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ex_result_Screenshot` FOREIGN KEY (`Screenshot_FID`) REFERENCES `main_filestore` (`F_ID`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ex_result_self` FOREIGN KEY (`ParentResult_ID`) REFERENCES `ex_result` (`Result_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ex_result_session` FOREIGN KEY (`Session_ID`) REFERENCES `ex_session` (`Session_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This code is responsible for Inserting the records into the above table row-by-row.

```
 Private Sub insertRow_inner(ByVal row As DataRow)

    Dim sql = "INSERT INTO ex_result (Result_ID, ParentResult_ID, StepNumber, Name, Type, DB_ID, Session_ID, Status, TotalTime, FunctionCall, FunctionResult, ToolTime, PluginName, Screenshot_FID, IsNegative, ContinueOnError, WantSnapshot, Message, ResultCode, Output, InputArguments) VALUES (@Result_ID, @ParentResult_ID, @StepNumber, @Name, @Type, @DB_ID, @Session_ID, @Status, @TotalTime, @FunctionCall, @FunctionResult, @ToolTime, @PluginName, @Screenshot_FID, @IsNegative, @ContinueOnError, @WantSnapshot, @Message, @ResultCode, @Output, @InputArguments)"

    addParameter("@Result_ID", row("Result_ID"))
    addParameter("@ParentResult_ID", row("ParentResult_ID"))
    addParameter("@StepNumber", row("StepNumber"))
    addParameter("@Name", row("Name"))
    addParameter("@Type", row("Type"))
    addParameter("@DB_ID", row("DB_ID"))
    addParameter("@Session_ID", row("Session_ID"))
    addParameter("@Status", row("Status"))
    addParameter("@TotalTime", row("TotalTime"))
    addParameter("@FunctionCall", row("FunctionCall"))
    addParameter("@FunctionResult", row("FunctionResult"))
    addParameter("@ToolTime", row("ToolTime"))
    addParameter("@PluginName", row("PluginName"))
    addParameter("@Screenshot_FID", row("Screenshot_FID"))
    addParameter("@IsNegative", row("IsNegative"))
    addParameter("@ContinueOnError", row("ContinueOnError"))
    addParameter("@WantSnapshot", row("WantSnapshot"))
    addParameter("@Message", row("Message"))
    addParameter("@ResultCode", row("ResultCode"))
    addParameter("@Output", row("Output"))
    addParameter("@InputArguments", row("InputArguments"))

    ExecuteDML(sql)
End Sub
```

What i observed here, that the **Deadlock was occuring randomly**. For example, it **might fail for the 10th record(row), and on retrying, it failed on the 15th record(row)**. Also, if it was under Transaction, then we cannot retry the insertion(need to restart transaction). If mainDBM is not under Transaction, then **on second retry of inserting the row(see below code)**, it got inserted.

```
For Each row As DataRow In resultTable.Rows
    Dim trials = 0
    While trials < 5
        trials += 1
        Try
            Me.insertRow_inner(row)
            Exit While
        Catch ex As Exception
            logger.Warning("{0} | - {1}", trials, ex.Message)
        End Try
    End While
Next
```

Any idea what might be causing the deadlocks?

Comment: What actions happen on the affected system in parallel to the import?

Deadlocks only happen when *two or more* client transactions try to lock the same things, but in different order. 

Check SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS right after getting a deadlock error message, it will contain detailed information on the most recent deadlock seen ...

Comment: Two things might be happening with different connections
  1. Same code might be running
  2. A MySql Event might be deleting some records from the same table.

I will try disabling the MySqlEvent, and then retry, and shall note the STATUS of INNODB ENGINE when Deadlocks occur.

Comment: @HartmutHolzgraefe Your suggestion was helpful. I found out that the Deadlock was due to the Event. Please Post your comment as an answer.